# Expand an element from the center outwards, ignoring div boundries

Tags: jquery, html, css

I suspect this may be simple to answer and there's something obvious I'm missing, but I'm at a bit of a loss right now. I have a div with an image in the background. When clicked, I have another div (shaped as a circle via border-radius) which I would like to expand from the center of the first div, past the boundaries of that div, effectively circle-wiping it to a colour. Getting the circle to expand is no problem, but (presumably because of the way the circle is centered in the initial div) I can't seem to get it to expand past the left / top boundaries— once it hits them, it continues to expand to the right and bottom.

Here's the simple animation code:

```
$(".projectContainer").click(function(){
  $(".circle").animate({
        width:'+=600px',
        height:'+=600px'},600);
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="projectContainer" id="A Head In The Box">
    <div class="circleContCont"><div class="circleCont">
            <div class="circle"></div>
    </div></div>
</div>
```

and the CSS for the various elements:

```
.projectContainer {
   width:384px;
   height:288px;
   max-width:100%;
   background-color:#FFF;
   background-position: center center;
   display:inline-block;
   margin:7px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
.circleContCont {
   display:table;
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
   vertical-align:middle;
}

.circleCont {
   overflow:hidden;
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle;
}

.circle {
   width:0px;
   height:0px;
   margin-left: auto; 
   margin-right: auto;
   background: #FFF;
   border-radius: 50%;
   z-index:2;
}
```

The centering code is taken from [here](http://emergentweb.com/test/valign.html), as I haven't been able to get it to work any other way. It seems like a bit of a messy work-around though, there might well be an easier way to do it.

**Edit:** after setting the circle's position to absolute and animating the top and left values (-=300px) as well, the circle can now move beyond the containing div. I can not get it to remain centered, however. [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUfe6tzUgNo&feature=youtu.be) a video showing how it WAS working, and [here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QI5zYwIJTSc) a video that shows how it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Position your circle absolutely and then use the following code for an animated effect

```
$(".projectContainer").click(function(){
  $(".circle").animate({
      width:'+=600px',
      left:'-=300px',
      top: '-=300px',
      height:'+=600px'
   },600);
});
```

check this, click on the circle

```js
$(".circle").click(function() {
  $(".circle").animate({
    'width': '+=600px',
    'left': '-=300px',
    'top': '-=300px',
    'height': '+=600px'
  }, 600);
});
```

```css
.circle {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work on my end, possibly something conflicting with the code that centers it initially. The circle will expand beyond the div, but it is no longer centered. [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QI5zYwIJTSc&feature=youtu.be) a video I recorded of what's happening

Comment: is the circle positioned absolutely?

Comment: Yep, positioned absolutely!

Comment: its hard to say anything without looking at the rest of the code. anyway this is how it is done :)